# Exception Erring Out though handled

Tags: java, exception

Below is the code that I was trying to understand.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("NullPointerException");
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
}
```

Everything is fine except when I am throwing **new Exception();**. So when I am doing so an error is occurring saying, "Unhandled exception type Exception" though I have provided the catch statement below to handle it.

So I know the solution to the problem but I want to know the reason. What are the insights that I am missing.

Can anybody explain it.

Comment: The exception is not thrown from the try block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> though I have provided the catch statement below to handle it.

A `catch` block only handles exceptions in the corresponding `try` block. Your `throw new Exception();` statement is in a `catch` block instead - and likewise you're currently throwing `NullPointerException` from a `catch` block, and that *won't* be caught by the catch block below it. The compiler knows that the `catch (Exception e)` block does not handle the exception thrown in the `catch (NullPointerException e)` block, and therefore it gives you a compile-time error just as if you had that `throw` statement without any `try`/`catch` at all.

If you change your code to:

```
try
{
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    throw new Exception();
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
}
catch (NullPointerException e)
{
    System.out.println("NullPointerException");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

... then it should compile and be fine.

If you want to handle exceptions thrown from a `catch` block, then you'll need nested `try` blocks. For example:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("NullPointerException");
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
```

Now, consider what happens if you run this with no command line arguments:

- The inner `try` block will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
- The first `catch` block will catch the exception, print a message to the console, and then throw `NullPointerException`
- The *final* `catch` block will catch the `NullPointerException` and print just "Exception" to the console. Importantly, the `catch (NullPointerException e)` block will *not* catch that exception, because the exception  wasn't thrown from the `try` block that it's associated with

Note that having nested try/catch blocks like this is relatively rarely a good idea. It's fine in terms of trying to understand how exceptions work in Java, but not a good idea in real code. (Likewise catching `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `NullPointerException` is rarely a good idea in real code.)

Comment: @VarunJain: Then you need that `catch` block to be inside a `try` block. I'll edit my answer to show how that would work - but I definitely *do* understand the problem itself. I may not know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but that's a different matter... (You only said you were trying to *understand* the code, which is why I've *explained* it.)

Comment: Really sorry for the language. Didn't do it to insult anybody here.